# Trying to "build" a query using LiveCode to get docs from Mongo

Tags: mongodb, livecode

I'm continuing practicing with LiveCode and MongoDB. I made a stack with a button with a script connecting to my local MongoDB instance. This script "builds" a query. When my code produces this:

```
C:\mongodb\bin\mongo.exe localhost:27017/BatGar --eval "var c=db.BatRegis.find(); while(c.hasNext()) printjson(c.next())"
```

I get documents from the server.

But when my code produces:

```
C:\mongodb\bin\mongo.exe localhost:27017/BatGar --eval "var c=db.BatRegis.find({"inspec":"No"}); while(c.hasNext()) printjson(c.next())"
```

or

```
C:\mongodb\bin\mongo.exe localhost:27017/BatGar --eval "var c=db.BatRegis.find({inspec:"No"}); while(c.hasNext()) printjson(c.next())"
```

I get error:

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.2.7
connecting to: localhost:27017/BatGar
Thu Apr 03 20:35:30 ReferenceError: No is not defined (shell eval):1
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Quoting. Your "" are cutting off at the start of "No".

Comment: Replacing the double quotes with single quotes solved the problem, now it's a matter of expanding the script to make everything variable by populating the querry with values entered in fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use curly quotes or single quotes:

```
C:\mongodb\bin\mongo.exe localhost:27017/BatGar --eval "var c=db.BatRegis.find({inspec:`No`}); while(c.hasNext()) printjson(c.next())"
```

or

```
C:\mongodb\bin\mongo.exe localhost:27017/BatGar --eval "var c=db.BatRegis.find({inspec'No'}); while(c.hasNext()) printjson(c.next())"
```